# Kusto user defined aggregate function

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I am looking to create a user defined aggregate function in KQL to be used in a summarize function. I want to calculate the average value of a device sensor, but I need it to include the duration of time when a sensor has a specific value.

I've searched online, in the Microsoft documentation and StackOverflow, but I am unable to find any example that may help.

Note: The code examples in this question are slimmed down to just include the relevant information.

My table setup is as follows:

```
.create table tempMetrics (
    TimeStamp: datetime,
    Name: string,
    Value: decimal
    )
```

Let's use this as input data:

```
.ingest inline into table tempMetrics <|
datetime(2024-01-03 10:00:00),Sensor1,1
datetime(2024-01-03 10:03:00),Sensor1,5
datetime(2024-01-03 10:05:00),Sensor1,3
datetime(2024-01-03 10:06:00),Sensor1,7
datetime(2024-01-03 10:00:00),Sensor2,5
datetime(2024-01-03 10:02:00),Sensor2,6
datetime(2024-01-03 10:05:00),Sensor2,3
datetime(2024-01-03 10:09:00),Sensor2,1
```

I want to calculate the average value per five minutes, per metric. A simple query to get this would be:

```
tempMetrics
| summarize Average=avg(Value) by bin(TimeStamp, 5m), Name
```

However, I want it to be the average over time.
So if a sensor measures `1` at the start of the time block, and three minutes in the value changes to `5`, the average shouldn't be `3`, but `2.6`.

Above query gives the following results.

| TimeStamp | Name | Average | Should be |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-03T10:00:00Z | Sensor1 | 3 | 2.6 |
| 2024-01-03T10:00:00Z | Sensor2 | 5.5 | 5.6 |
| 2024-01-03T10:05:00Z | Sensor1 | 5 | 6.2 |
| 2024-01-03T10:05:00Z | Sensor2 | 2 | 2.6 |

I want to solve this using a user defined aggregate function, because this would keep the query clean.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you to use the `range` operator to create a time series for each sensor and then summarize with average over time and Name.

```
tempMetrics
| extend TimeSlot = range(bin(TimeStamp, 5m), bin(TimeStamp + 5m, 5m), 1m)
| summarize Average = avg(Value) by TimeSlot, Name
```

EDIT: This solution assumes that the time intervals are aligned, and it might need adjustments.

Comment: This seems to create a series for each sensor, regardless of a value that may overlap. Unfortunately the intervals are not aligned. The devices generating this data will send it when a sensor value changes and it can be completely random.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a user defined function for finding this average is not possible. You can directly create the logics with the existing functions in Kusto. Below is the code.

```
let tempMetrics = datatable(TimeStamp:datetime, Name:string, Value:decimal)
[
    datetime(2024-01-03 10:00:00), 'Sensor1', 1,
    datetime(2024-01-03 10:03:00), 'Sensor1', 5,
    datetime(2024-01-03 10:05:00), 'Sensor1', 3,
    datetime(2024-01-03 10:06:00), 'Sensor1', 7,
    datetime(2024-01-03 10:00:00), 'Sensor2', 5,
    datetime(2024-01-03 10:02:00), 'Sensor2', 6,
    datetime(2024-01-03 10:05:00), 'Sensor2', 3,
    datetime(2024-01-03 10:09:00), 'Sensor2', 1,
];
tempMetrics
| partition hint.strategy=native by Name
(
 make-series Value = max(Value) default=long(null) on TimeStamp from datetime("2024-01-03 10:00:00") to datetime("2024-01-03 10:10:00")   step 1m
 | project Name , Value, TimeStamp
)
|  mv-expand TimeStamp, Value=series_fill_forward(Value)
| extend TimeStamp=todatetime(TimeStamp), Value= tolong(Value)
| summarize Average=avg(Value) by bin(TimeStamp, 5m), Name
| where  isnan(Average)==0
```

This code uses the make-series operator to create a time series of the maximum value for each metric, and then uses mv-expand to expand and fill in any missing values. Finally, it uses summarize to calculate the average value per five minutes, per metric.

**Output**

| TimeStamp | Name | Average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-03T10:00:00Z | Sensor1 | 2.6 |
| 2024-01-03T10:00:00Z | Sensor2 | 5.6 |
| 2024-01-03T10:05:00Z | Sensor1 | 6.2 |
| 2024-01-03T10:05:00Z | Sensor2 | 2.6 |

Comment: This may work, and there are a lot of ways to calculate the timed average. I want to store this in a Materialized View however and that will not be possible with a `partition` statement. I will further investigate and post on StackOverflow if any useful technique is found.

Answer (score 0):

I have had contact with a Microsoft Cloud Solution Architect, who is assisting us and he has confirmed that it is **not** possible to create a user defined aggregate function.

The query is to be used in a Materialized View, so serialization is not possible (`order by`, `partition`, etc.). For this reason I was looking into creating a user defined function. As this is not possible, I will look into other possibilities.

Comment: Okay. let us know the other possible answers to solve this.